# In Vue, how can I use dynamically created computed in v-model

Tags: vue.js

I have data which is like:

```
const entries = ref([{scopes: ["a", "b"]}])
```

And a Vue template which iterates over all `entries` and wants to create an input box for `scopes` field. So I made the following helper:

```fs
function computedScopes(scopes: Ref<string[]>): WritableComputedRef<string> {
  return computed({
    get() {
      return scopes.value.join(" ")
    },
    set(value) {
      scopes.value = value.split(" ")
    },
  })
}
```

```js
<template v-for="(entry, i) in entries" :key="i">
  <input type="string" v-model="computedScopes(entry.scopes)" />
</template>
```

But I get the following error:

```
v-model value must be a valid JavaScript member expression
```

How can I from template create a proxy object which would map between a space-separated string and an array of strings?

Comment: "How can I from template" - you shouldn't, it's not a replacement for script. It doesn't make sense to create a computed in a template because an expression is called on each template render, not to mention that it's not compatible with v-model syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here using v-model is not the best practice,because it has limitations ,It's easy to understand if you know how v-model works ,[check here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Consider adding the relevant code to the answer, it needs to be understandable without navigating to a link that may become unavailable

Comment: Sure, I can split computed into getter and setter and use it as prop and event handler myself, but I think the whole idea of writable computed is that this is abstracted away.